# Configuring Glacier Deep Archive transition rule with Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I want to configure object lifecycle rule of a S3 bucket with Cloudformation, specifically under the Glacier Deep Archive storage class but I am seeing some weird error.

DEEP_ARCHIVE is clearly an acceptable storage class as documented here: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule-transition.html)

But upon applying the template I get

```
Value of StorageClass property must be in [STANDARD_IA, GLACIER, Glacier, ONEZONE_IA, INTELLIGENT_TIERING]
```

what's going on?

Comment: Had the same issue a few weeks ago, contacted amazon support and it seems that it's not yet available via CloudFormation (like so often for new resources)

Comment: Ha. That's what I suspected too, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible as of [21 Nov 2019](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html).